# Group variety $PGL(n)$

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Sorry for my bad English.

In Hartshorne’s algebraic geometry III.example 10.7.2, projective space $\mathbb{P}_k^n$ is acted by $G＝$PGL($n)$.

But,I can’t understand why is $G$ group variety?

In general, when we are gave any group $H$, can we construct group variety $H$？

Comment: To comment on your second question: any finite group is a subgroup of the general linear group by first embedding it in a symmetric group (via Cayley's Theorem) and then representing the symmetric group as permutation matrices. In general anything described by purely algebraic means is probably an algebraic group, but analytic constructions lead you out of the strictly algebraic category (these notes by Borcherds explain the Heisenberg Group https://math.berkeley.edu/~reb/courses/261/3.pdf)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One can define the group variety $\operatorname{PGL}(n)$ as an open subvariety of $P M_n$; the Zariski open subset where the determinant is nonzero. The group law is given by polynomial equations, so that gives an algebraic group.